# Access parent controller data from main controller

Tags: angularjs

I have the following MainController:

```
function MainController($scope, DataService) {

  $scope.model = {
    data: null
  }

  $scope.init = function () {
    DataService.GetById(2)
      .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {        
         $scope.model.data = data;
      })
  };

  $scope.init();

}
```

I then have a child controller where I need to access the parent scope:

```
function ChildController($scope) {

  $scope.model = {
    data: null
  }

  $scope.init = function () {
    #scope.model.data = $scope.$parent.model.data;
  };

  $scope.init();

}
```

I get an error saying $scope.$parent.model.data is null.

If I check the console $scope.$parent.model.data seems null but if I click it I see that it is not and it has the correct data ...

I believe the problem is I am defining the data in ChildController before it has been defined in the MainController due to DataService.GetById which queries the database ...

Am I right?

How can I solve this?

Comment: you can directly access the parent scope variables in your child controller .Why are we manually trying to assign it here using $parent

Comment: Can you show us your view with the nesting of the controllers?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/divm/7qqp1h2j/1/

Comment: Do you want child data to inherit parent or have its own copy?

Comment: I want one of the child properties to be the same as the parent property, e.g., data ... But child controller has other properties not related to parent properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right: the problem you have, is that your parent controller populates "data" inside a promise.

To understand what a promise is, you can check this : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

When your child controller is run, the promise will certainly not have returned yet.

**The first way to handle that is adding a watch :**

```
function ChildController($scope) {

  $scope.model = {
    data: null
  }

  $scope.init = function () {
    //$scope.model.data = $scope.$parent.model.data;
   var watchRemover = $scope.$watch('$parent.model.data', function(newVal, oldVal){
        if (newVal !== oldVal && newVal !== null){
           $scope.model.data = $scope.$parent.model.data;
           watchRemover();
        }
   })
  };

  $scope.init();

}
```

**Another solution is to handle it with events :**

***Parent controller :***

```
 DataService.GetById(2)
  .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {        
     $scope.model.data = data;
     $scope.$broadcast("data loaded");
  });
```

***child controller :***

```
$scope.$on("data loaded", function(){
     $scope.model.data = $scope.$parent.model.data;
});
```

Comment: The broadcast option worked really fine ... And it seems nicer then watch, no?

Comment: I think so. That's why I came back to my answer and edited it

Answer (score 1):

While setting up watches or using broadcast/edit is fine, I think a simpler solution would be binding one level upper.

Change `$scope.model.data = $scope.$parent.model.data;`
to `$scope.model= $scope.$parent.model;`

In this bind whenever `$scope.$parent.model.data` change, it will also be reflected in `$scope.model.data`. Be careful the reverse is also true, though.

**Edit:** On second thought, this approach won't help OP if he's not handling null correctly in the child controller, or else the original code would have worked. My approach is useful when `$scope.$parent.model.data` changes, it will be automatically available in child.